# Snapping centers of objects in map canvas QGIS

Tags: qgis, vector-layer, digitizing, mapcanvas

I wanna snap object to object basing on their centers in map canvas. For instance, snap center of green polygon to the center of red one. Already stwitched on snapping options (see below). Is there any way to figure it out?

[image][image]